# Lookup value from data Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of postcodes coordinates in a `df`

```
print(df)
out[0]:
    X                      Y           Postcode
84060.2933273726    452334.434562507      2543
842443.2065506417   452310.49440726795    2544
78129.7656972764    450394.36304550205    2542
76143.40136149981   452922.516876715      2551
```

I also have an activity file (`df2`), with unknown coordinates are stated by NaN.

```
print(df2)
out[1]:
    OrigLoc DestLoc O_X               O_Y             D_X           D_Y
0   2515    2515    82190.12097       454778.5460     81694.8038    454266.4303
1   2515    2544    81203.80496       453952.5966     NaN           NaN
2   2544    2515    NaN               NaN             81759.58454   454494.4784
3   2515    2543    81573.1442        454424.602      NaN           NaN
```

How can I fill the NaNs in O_X, O_Y, D_X, and D_Y by taking the data of X and Y coordinate from `df`? I have tried to use pd.merge, but since I want to find values for multiple column, does it mean that I have to do pd.merge 4 times? Is there a more efficient way to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A merge will get you the coordinates of the origin or of the destination, so 2 merges should be enough:

```
>>> orig = df2.reset_index().merge(df, left_on='OrigLoc', right_on='Postcode')\
...           .set_index('index')[['X', 'Y']].add_prefix('O_')
>>> orig
                 O_X            O_Y
index                              
2      842443.206551  452310.494407
>>> dest = df2.reset_index().merge(df, left_on='DestLoc', right_on='Postcode')\
...           .set_index('index')[['X', 'Y']].add_prefix('D_')
>>> dest
                 D_X            D_Y
index                              
1      842443.206551  452310.494407
3       84060.293327  452334.434563
```

Note how these `orig` and `dest` dataframe have the same column names than your coordinates in `df`: `O_X`, `O_Y`, `D_X`, `D_Y`. You should also note the `reset_index` and `set_index` steps which allow to preserve the original index − `merge` usually erases that column. All this allows us to keep the information of which cells in `df2` these values should fill.

We can now simply use `fillna` to fill in the gaps in df:

```
>>> df2.fillna(dest).fillna(orig)
   OrigLoc  DestLoc            O_X            O_Y            D_X            D_Y
0     2515     2515   82190.120970  454778.546000   81694.803800  454266.430300
1     2515     2544   81203.804960  453952.596600  842443.206551  452310.494407
2     2544     2515  842443.206551  452310.494407   81759.584540  454494.478400
3     2515     2543   81573.144200  454424.602000   84060.293327  452334.434563
```